# Classic ASP Installed VB6 DLL works locally, but fails remotely

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vb6

I have had to do some repairs to a legacy classic asp website that uses some VB6 activeX dll's

All of the changes that I have made work completely and have been fully tested on my local machine (windows 8.1), I have deployed to the servers.

1. drainstop
2. iisreset
3. copy files
4. regsvr32 any new dll's
5. start after drainstop.

All of the code is working on each of the servers after deployment, but when I use the public side of the site, the changes do not work.

I have looked at the event log and cannot find any problems

Answer (score 0):

This is either permission issue in your Component Services for the objects you've registered, or a setting in your Application pool.  Make sure you have `Enable 32 bit applications` to `true` and see how often it's recycling.  But since you're not seeing anything in the event log about it, it's probably not the recycling.